# Explicit uv.x value forms a horizontal line with length function

Tags: glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

I am trying to get better with something as complex as glsl but it's taking some time to grasp certain concepts coming from a PHP/JS background.

In the following fragment shader code, I don't understand why are we getting a horizontal bar in the center?

The origin is shifted to the center, fine.
And when I `+=`or `-=` the `uv.x` value, it's adding or subtracting the `.x` value for **each** pixel. That is also understood as doing this moves the resultant circle around.

But when you change this `-=` or `+=` to just `=` it should mean that every pixel gets its `.x` value **fixed** to be `.2`(in this case) which should give a messed up graphic as every pixel is moving itself to the `.2` spot on x-axis? Could someone please explain in layman terms? Thanks.

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

void main(){
  vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
  uv.x *= u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y;

  // Remap the space to -1. to 1.
  uv = uv *2.-1.;

  // The following will move the circle around
  // uv.x += 0.2;
  // uv.x -= 0.2;

  // But why does this creates the horizontal bar?
  uv.x = .2;

  // Visualize the distance field
  gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(step( .3, length(uv))),1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

The result of `length(vec2(0.2, uv.y))` is equal for all the pixels in one row.

---

The fragment shader is executed (concurrently) for each fragment and the built-in fragment shader input variable [`gl_FragCoord.xy`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml) is different for each fragment. It ranges from (0, 0) for the bottom left fragment to (*width*, *height*) for the top right fragment. Therefore the `uv` coordinate ranges from (-1*aspect, -1) to (1*acpect, 1).

```c
vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
uv.x *= u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y;
```

The output color of the fragment shader depends on the `uv` coordiante:

```c
gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(step( .3, length(uv))), 1.0);
```

`length(uv)` calculates the length of the vector `uv`. The result increases circularly starting from point (0, 0). If you add a constant to the components of the coordinates (e.g. `length(vec2(uv.x + 0.2, uv.y - 0.2))`, the result still depends on the two components, resulting in a circle.
This changes if you set one component of the coordinate `uv` to a constant value. Because then this component is no longer different for each fragment. Instead of setting `uv.x = .2`, you can also replace the expression by `length(vec2(0.2, uv.y))`. This way the result depends only on the y-component of the uv-coordinate, resulting in a bar instead of a circular shape.

Comment: "length(uv) calculates the length of the vector uv." yes but when I say that give me length(uv), what is uv here? The current pixel coordinate or the origin?

Comment: @Mr.Coder The fragment shader is executed (concurrently) for each fragment and the built-in fragment shader input variable `gl_FragCoord.xy` is different for each fragment. It ranges from (0, 0) for the bottom left fragment to (*width*, *height*) for the top right fragment. Therefore the `uv` coordinate ranges from (-1, -1) to (1, 1).

Comment: I understand these concepts, but what i am asking is say that the shader is running on a pixel at `vec2(0.8, 0.8)` which should be somewhere at the top right corner, so there if I ask for the `length( 0.2, uv.y)` does it mean that how far is this `vec2(0.8, 0.8)` from `vec2(0.2, 0.8)`?

Comment: No, `length(0.2, uv.y)` doesn't calculate the distance to a pixel. I only calculates the length of the vector `(0.2, uv.y)`. `uv.y` is different for each line or row, but 0.2 is a constant.

Comment: Rabbid, thank you for your patience, but I am trying to understand in layman's terms, so firstly 'each fragment' = ' each pixel'?

Secondly, 'length of the vector`(0.2, uv.y)` refers to 'firing a line from the `(0.0, 0.0)` origin (we moved this origin from bottom left to center) with an arrow at its end pointing towards fixed `.2` on x and the `y` value of each pixel that the code is running on, and then calculating how long this line with arrow is?

Comment: No. 0.2 is 0.2 for each pixel. `uv.y` is different for each row of pixel. The is no magic. This are just 2 values. The first on is constant and the second one is different for each row.

Comment: If this is indeed true, then I believe I understand it. Since `length`function will only return a value for checking and if for each  pixel if this length returns a length of less than `0.3` then it will paint black on that pixel or white if vice versa?

Comment: Now I changed `uv.x = 0.2` to `uv.x = 0.0` and it returns the same horizontal bar result. 

That `0.2` was not needed as it doesnt matter what the x is changed to because it's going to remain constant for each pixel's calculation. Am I rigiht?:)

Comment: Yes. The result of `length(vec2(0, uv.y))` is equal for all the pixels in one row.

Comment: Thanks for the patience with a noobie. :)

Comment: One final question, assuming that I do end up using `uv.x = .2;`, this would mean that the origin has now shifted to `(0.2, 0)`?

Comment: No. The center of the horizontal bar is still y=0. x=0.2 just makes the bar narrower. `length(vec2(0.2, uv.y))` is always greater than `length(vec2(0, uv.y))`. Note `length(vec2(x, y))` == `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`

Comment: It's starting to make sense now. Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge. Glsl does take you on a wild brain adventure forcing you to think in a radically different way than other languages :)

Comment: The difference is concurrency. You can't think in loops or iterations. You have to think from the perspective of a single pixel (fragment). A single fragment decides what color it will end up with, and doesn't care about its neighbors. A color gradient between adjacent fragments is achieved only by an input that varies slightly between adjacent fragments.